# Get rid of leading 0 in Shopify Quantity selector

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I have a Shopify quantity selector that currently looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKAdy.png)

I want to get rid of the leading 0 that appears when I have quantity < 10. But I don't know how to do this. I've tried injecting a JS script that filters the 0 on input change but it doesn't work. I printed the filter output and it's correct, but I can't replace the HTML somehow. Here's my code:

```
<div {% if block != blank %}{{ block.shopify_attributes }}{% endif %} class="product-form__controls-group{% unless show_quantity_input %} hidden{% endunless %}">
  <div class="product-form__controls-label-wraper type-heading-3">
    <label for="Quantity-{{ section.id }}" >{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="product-form__item product-form__quantity">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function leading0(x, id){
          console.log(x, x.replace(/^0+/, ''), id);
          x = x.replace(/^0+/, '')
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '{{ x }}';
      }
    </script>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="product-form__quantity-button product-form__quantity-add-item "
      aria-label="{{ 'general.accessibility.quantity_subtract' | t }}"
      
    >
      {% render 'icon-plus', non_focusable: true %}
    </button>
    <input
      type="number" id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}"
      {% if form_id != blank %}form="{{ form_id }}"{% endif %}
      name="quantity" value="1" min="1" pattern="[0-9]"
      class="product-form__input product-form__input--quantity" data-quantity-input
      aria-label="{{ 'general.accessibility.quantity' | t }}"
      onchange="leading0(this.value, this.id);"
    >
    <button
      type="button"
      class="product-form__quantity-button product-form__quantity-subtract-item"
      aria-label="{{ 'general.accessibility.quantity_add' | t }}"
    >
      {% render 'icon-minus', non_focusable: true %}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this you need to change its value. as its input
`document.getElementById(id).value = x;`

Comment: @HardikSatasiya That solved it, tysm!!

Comment: Ok added the solution as the answer, please mark it as the correct answer. so for others it can be useful 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue by modifying your JavaScript a little bit.

> To set the value of `input` you can set `value` property.

```js
function leading0(x, id){
    console.log(x, x.replace(/^0+/, ''), id);
    x = x.replace(/^0+/, '')

    // document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '{{ x }}';
    // instead of this ^

    document.getElementById(id).value = x;
    // use this ^
}
```

if any doubts please comment.